# How to disable screen capture in Android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screenshot, layoutparams

Is it possible to disable screen capture from a fragment?
I know the below works for an Activity class

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

But what if I have a fragment which shows up on top of an activity. Can I somehow disable screen capture? I've tried to set the FLAG_SECURE in the onCreate() or onCreateView() method of the fragment, but it doesn't work. I'm still able to take screen shot. Only when I add the flag in parent activity I can disable it.

On a related note, say, I've a method in ParentActivity.java (which extends Activity)

```
public void disableScreenCapture() {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

}
```

And in my ChildFragment.java (which extends Fragment)

```
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ParentActivity parentActivity = (ParentActivity)getActivity();
                parentActivity.disableScreenCapture(); //doesn't work
        }
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ParentActivity parentActivity = (ParentActivity)getActivity();
                parentActivity.disableScreenCapture(); //doesn't work either
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My expectation is that the "secure" flag applies to the entire View UI layer. A SurfaceView's Surface is a separate layer and can be handled independently, but the View UI is composited by the app and handed to the system compositor as a single entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code worked for me.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    WindowManager wm = getActivity().getWindowManager();
    wm.removeViewImmediate(window.getDecorView());
    wm.addView(window.getDecorView(), window.getAttributes());

}
```

Comment: You great buddy :)

Comment: Did you add this code in your extend fragment class or securing the whole activity?

Comment: In the fragment's start or resume entry point, basically when u want to disable.

Comment: It works! The only issue left is that this will cause the screen to "blink". Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 9):

Performing your `disableScreenCapture()` call in `onResume`, `onCreateView` or `onActivityAttached` in your Fragment should all work - they did for me. Performing that call in `onActivityCreated` might not work as I believe that hook is only called when the Activity is being *re*-created, after it's destroyed. However, I didn't try that one.

If performing that call in `onCreateView` isn't working for you, are you 100% certain that your Fragment is actually being added to the Activity?

For a `DialogFragment` it's slightly different:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

A `DialogFragment` isn't a `Dialog` itself, but instead holds a reference to one and shows/dismisses it when the fragment is added and removed. Dialogs have their own Windows and must have the flag set individually.

Comment: What if my fragment extends from Fragment and not DialogFragment?

Comment: Oh sorry, I read the question wrong. Doing some research and will re-answer.

Comment: Disabling screenshot on onResume() or onActivityCreated() doesn't work either, in fragment.

Comment: All of the methods you tried worked for me when I tested them. Are you certain your Fragment is actually being added to your Activity?

Comment: I think so. Basically I've a single Activity and bunch of Fragments. I have a fragment switcher class which replaces current fragment with new fragment and then commits transaction. Looks okay to me on the surface. Let me dig deeper in my code.

Comment: SOmething to do with the way I replace fragments that simply setting the flag didn't work for me. However, I found a solution that works. Posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public function in Parent activity and set flag onAttach method of fragment and clear flag in onDetach Method.

Method in Parent Activity

```
fun disableScreenShot(isSecure:Boolean){
    if (isSecure) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
    else{
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    }
}
```

Code in Fragment

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        activity = context as HomeActivity
        activity.disableScreenShot(true)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        activity.disableScreenShot(false)
    }
```