# Disabling screen capture in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, screenshot

As the per android documentation, we can disable screen/video capture in an activity like

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

But how do I achieve the same in a fragment.
For example, say I have an activity which has five fragments, but I want to disable screen/video capture only in one of the five fragments and not in other fragments.

Doing this is

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

inside a fragment disables screen/video capture in all the fragments.

Should I write logic for enabling/disabling screen capture in the activity based on the fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573371/how-to-disable-screen-capture-in-android-fragment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573371/how-to-disable-screen-capture-in-android-fragment
 answers the questions on how to disable screen capture inside a fragment but my question is how to achieve that in one of the many fragments

Comment: use this inside oncreateview method of the fragment that you want to ss disable `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

Answer (score 5):

`FLAG_SECURE` is a window-level capability; you cannot apply it to only portion of a window (e.g., one fragment in an activity).

If by "an activity which has five fragments", you mean "an activity which has five fragments on the screen at the same time", then AFAIK you cannot accomplish what you want.

If by "an activity which has five fragments", you mean "an activity which has five fragments, of which only one is visible at a time, such as pages in a `ViewPager`", then you would need to toggle `FLAG_SECURE` as that activity enters and leaves the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use your fragment in a single activity and set the flags. As fragments are just a way to reference and change views in an activity the android does not have a secure model to them.